# Avoiding tooltip collisions in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

The have a set or markers with divIcons and bound to tooltips, but there are so many they collide. I'd like to make the tooltips intelligently workout which direction is best so that they do not collide but I have yet to find a plugin that does quite the right thing. My plan is to just run a simple latitude check that if they are within ? degrees of latitude and ? degrees of longitude then the one with the smaller longitude has direction:left and the other right. It happens that my data only has to deal with two tooltips colliding at once, there's never a third in the mix.

I would be very surprised if no-one else has ever had to solve this so I'm hoping someone else has and made their work available.

I already have clustering, and hide the tooltips when zoomed out.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#clusteringdecluttering

Comment: @IvanSanchez I've read through all of them but none of them do quite the right thing.